# How to convert changing numbers (mix double/ integer) to objects in a NSMutableArray?

Tags: objective-c

I am wrestling with this problem. I have a NSMutableArray like

```
NSMutableArray *t =[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity: 2000];
```

How do I change this JAVA language with counter int i and double dt

```
t[i+1] = t[1] + i * dt
```

into Objective C?

`t[i+1] = t[1] + [NSNumber numberWithDouble: i*dt]` does not work.

Comment: this is invalid code: `[NSMutableArray *t] =[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity: 2000];`, give us your real code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
[t replaceObjectAtIndex:(i+1) 
             withObject:[NSNumber numberWithDouble: (i*dt +  [[t objectAtIndex:1] doubleValue])]];
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `NSNumber`s and if you need the array filled with 0's you will need to add them first then replace the object.

```
NSNumber *zero = @0;
for(size_t i = 0; i < 2000; ++i)
    [t addObject:zero];

[t replaceObjectAtIndex:i+1 
             withObject:@([[t objectAtIndex:1] doubleValue] + i * dt)];
```